# Google Sheets Apps Script Logger

Tags: google-apps-script, logging

I am using Safari on a Mac, and when I open the Apps Script page, I do not have the menus that allow me to view the Logger.log 'files.'

Is there a way to turn that on?

Thanks!!

I also tried it on Chrome and had the same problem. Attached is a screenshot of the menus.

[image: Screen shot of Menus]

Comment: Perhaps you know more than I but I'm not familiar with any logger files.

Comment: Are you referring to execution log in the bottom part of the editor page where you can see the output of `Logger.log`?

Comment: Tried the last two buttons on the left panel?